# Conditional date format in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am formatting the current date in an AIR Mobile project in the following way:

```
var dateFormatter:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter( Capabilities.language );
dateFormatter.setDateTimePattern("EEEE d");
trace(dateFormatter.format(date));
```

This works perfect, but since I have a width restriction (only 12 characters can be displayed) the problem is that in certain languages like Portuguese, the EEEE format returns `Segunda-feria` meaning that the number of characters would be 16 (including day number).

Is there a way to put conditional formatting meaning that EEEE cannot exceed more than 10 characters? (i.e: use EEEE always but if it exceeds more than 12 characters display EEE)

Comment: Then what would you want it to be displayed as? One way is to gather the string length and have it shorten with dateString.splice(12, dateString.length)

Comment: There I added an example of what I am requesting.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var str_tmp: String ="";
var dateFormatter :DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter( Capabilities.language );

dateFormatter.setDateTimePattern("EEEE d");

//# check for larger than 12 chars
str_tmp = dateFormatter.format(date);
if ( str_tmp.length > 12 ) { dateFormatter.setDateTimePattern("EEE d"); }

trace(dateFormatter.format(date));
```